# MySQL: Perform join on all rows of a table

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have a view where I combine some normalized tables. Based on a "master" table, I join connected tables (e.g. `JOIN child ON master.child_fk = child.pk`). This is pretty straight forward. Now, I'd like to extend this query to perform a join on ALL child rows in some special cases, for example if the `master.child_fk` equals to `-1`.

I managed to get a working query by creating a view where I duplicate all rows and set the pk to `-1` in the duplicates, but this is incredibly slow (I have quite a lot of data). The same result could be produced by iterating over all the `child.pk`s and performing a separate join for each, but I can't imagine that being faster.

What would be the best way to go about this using MySQL? Please ask questions if something is not clear.

edit: I can add that it seems the reason why my attempt was slow was because of poor index utliziation. See attached `EXPLAIN` output here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4IRG.png

Comment: replace your join condition as `JOIN child ON CASE WHEN master.child_fk != -1 THEN master.child_fk = child.pk ELSE 1 END)`
Can you paste your query?

Comment: I love you. It worked perfectly :)

Comment: i have updated it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your join condition as `JOIN child ON CASE WHEN master.child_fk != -1 THEN master.child_fk = child.pk ELSE 1 END)`